# Time series Clustering

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a number of sensors measuring a Temperature (or some other physical attribute) data. Does anyone know of any clustering method that can tell which sensors are showing similar patterns and behaviors? My series are showing some trends with cycles.

I am very new to Time series analysis.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming (may be better suited for either http://stats.stackexchange.com or http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question is **too broad**. Enough to fill whole books on time series analysis...

Comment: I just need some pointers for state of the art time series clustering methods, in a  comment, I have heard dynamic time warping plus spectral clustering could work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Basic K-means clustering works fine for most kinds of sensor data.  You will need to take time slices to avoid auto-regressive issues.  Check out the proc in R